# Weird blinking of lights when trying to run the OWASPBWAP with one core count on laptop

Tags: windows, security, intel, processor, capslock

I was trying to install OSWAP-BWA on my laptop. I initially started the processor core count with 1. After completing the configuration, I tried to start the application. The laptop started to blink the Caps Lock light on the keyboard, as well as the HP logo light on the external HP keyboard. This incident happened on Windows 11, on an Intel 10700H series processor. On the other hand, my old laptop with an Intel 4210U series processor running on Kali Linux works fine when running with one processor core.[Blinking image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58KwK.jpg)

Things that i did:
Updating my drivers
Disabling any unnecessary startup programs
Reinstalling OSWAP-BWA

Running it with 2 cores solved the problem on my 10700H laptop. However, I am still wondering why I couldn't run it on 1 core, while my older generation CPU could handle it.

Note that system configuration for both OSWAP-BWA on virtual box is same. 1024 MB of RAM